# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk's latest platform version is outdated

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, update, ruby, elastic-beanstalk

When creating my Elastic Beanstalk application, I selected the latest platform version of Amazon Linux running Ruby (Puma). But, it has an outdated version (compared to the current stable version) of Ruby & Bundler.

How can I create an EC2 instance with up-to-date software for running a Ruby app with Puma?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

Comment: AWS packages are often a way behind current, they don't have mysql 5.7. You sometimes need to specify versions, so "yum install mysql56" instead of "you install mysql". You may have to install another repository outside AWS, though I don't know how to do that because I never tried.